# Bootbox message box doesn't fit content

Tags: html, height, message, confirm, bootbox

[image: Confirm bootbox]

```
                bootbox.confirm({
                    title: "請輸入綁定手機號碼",
                    message:
                        '<div class="col-xs-12">'
                        +   '<form class="form-horizontal">'
                        +       '<div class="form-group">'
                        +           '<label class="col-xs-12" style="text-align: left">帳號(您的手機號碼):</label>'
                        +           '<div class="col-xs-5">'
                        +               '<select class="form-control" id="countryCode-bootbox" name="countryCode-bootbox">'
                        +                   '<option value="+93">Afghanistan +93</option>'
                        +                   '<option value="+355">Albania +355</option>'
                        +                   '<option value="+213">Algeria +213</option>'
                        +                   '<option value="+1684">American Samoa +1684</option>'
                        +                   '<option value="+263">Zimbabwe +263</option>'
                        +               '</select>'
                        +           '</div>'
                        +           '<div class="col-xs-7">'
                        +               '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="cellphone-bootbox" name="cellphone-bootbox">'
                        +           '</div>'
                        +       '</div>'
                        +   '</form>'
                        + '</div>',
                    callback:
                        function(result) {
                            if(result == false) {
                                return;
                            }

                            register3rdPartyUser(flag, $('#countryCode-bootbox').val(), $('#cellphone-bootbox').val());
                        }
                });
```

As you can see, there are two horizontal lines inside the overall box which I believe are the boundaries of the message content. The bottom line doesn't come after the message content when I'm using HTML for my string. How can I fix this issue? Is it a bug?

Comment: The `col` classes require a containing element with the `row` class. You can eliminate the col-xs-12 div, then either add `row` to the `form-group` or change it to `form-row`, assuming you're using Bootstrap 4.

Comment: @TiesonT. Awesome. It fixed the problem. Though I don't understand why formatting bootstrap properly affects bootbox message window.

Comment: Bootbox is (mostly) just a helper for building Bootstrap modals - it's all DOM elements and fancy CSS positioning and effects. That means the markup and styling of Bootbox's content is subject to the same caveats as any other Bootstrap-themed content - if you don't apply the correct classes, the result will not render correctly. That's what you see here - the `.col-` classes need a `.row` element as an immediate parent for the flex-box styles to work correctly. If you haven't yet, I'd read the documentation, specifically the grid system: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/

Comment: I know about the grid system. I guess it makes sense how everything needs to adhere to bootstrap's way of formatting layout to have things not go funny. Thanks a lot.